# Mysql Query Group by Last record and first record

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables which status table are connected with profile table. Profile table store unique tagId and status table store multiple duplicate tagid entry. I want to show group by tagid's last record and first record.

Table: profile
Note: tagId is Unique

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| tagId(PK) | blah2 | blah3 | blah4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
101         |
102         |
103         |
104         |
105         |
106         |
```

Table: status

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
statusId | tagId |  date      | height| weight |  statusType | blah2 | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 101   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
2        | 102   | 2010-01-01 | 5.7   |  300   |  single     | 
3        | 101   | 2015-01-01 | 5.6   |  310   |  married    |
4        | 103   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
5        | 104   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
6        | 101   | 2016-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  pregnant   |
7        | 101   | 2016-09-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  delivery   |
8        | 105   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
```

What I want to try group by first date and group by last statusType

Query Result will be:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| tagId |  date      | height| weight |  statusType | blah2 | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 101   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  delivery   |
| 102   | 2010-01-01 | 5.7   |  300   |  single     | 
| 103   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
| 104   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
| 105   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
```

But I can't success with it, I tried with this MySQL code

```
SELECT DISTINCT Profile.TagId,Status.date,Status.StatusType,Status.height,Status.weight FROM Profile 
LEFT JOIN Status ON Status.TagId = Profile.TagId 
Where Status.StatusId In( Select Max(Status.StatusId) From Status Group By      Status.TagId ) 
Group By Status.TagId ORDER BY Profile.TagId ASC, Status.TagId DESC
```

But it returns last date and last statustype , like this

Query Result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| tagId |  date      | height| weight |  statusType | blah2 | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 101   | 2016-09-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  delivery   |
| 102   | 2010-01-01 | 5.7   |  300   |  single     | 
| 103   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
| 104   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
| 105   | 2010-01-01 | 5.6   |  300   |  single     |
```

Comment: What is `height` and `weight`?

Comment: forget about height , weight @Reno

Comment: I just don't get it, but maybe it was easier to understand before

Comment: not mandatory height , weight , skip this column @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.tagId, 
                smin.`date`, smin.height, smin.weight,
                smax.StatusType 
FROM Profile AS p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT tagId, MAX(`date`) AS max_date, MIN(`date`) AS min_date 
   FROM Status
   GROUP BY tagId 
) AS s ON p.tagId = s.tagId
LEFT JOIN Status AS smin ON smin.tagId = p.tagId AND s.min_date = smin.`date`
LEFT JOIN Status AS smax ON smax.tagId = p.tagId AND s.max_date = smax.`date`
```

The query uses a derived table which returns minimum and maximum `date` values per `tagId`. Using these values we can join back to `Status` table and get `date`, `height` and `weight` values from the `Status` record having the *minimum* `date` value **and** `StatusType` value for the `Status` record having the *maximum* `date` value.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want this or not, but just try it, and hope I do not mistake your question;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d112/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE status
    (`statusId` int, `tagId` int, `date` date, `height` int, `weight` int, `statusType` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO status
    (`statusId`, `tagId`, `date`, `height`, `weight`, `statusType`)
VALUES
    (1, 101, '2010-01-01', 5.6, 300, 'single'),
    (2, 102, '2010-01-01', 5.7, 300, 'single'),
    (3, 101, '2015-01-01', 5.6, 310, 'married'),
    (4, 103, '2010-01-01', 5.6, 300, 'single'),
    (5, 104, '2010-01-01', 5.6, 300, 'single'),
    (6, 101, '2016-01-01', 5.6, 300, 'pregnant'),
    (7, 101, '2016-09-01', 5.6, 300, 'delivery'),
    (8, 105, '2010-01-01', 5.6, 300, 'single')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select f.`tagId`, date_format(l.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as `date`, f.`statusType`
from (
    select s.*
    from `status` s
    inner join (
        select max(`statusId`) as `statusId`, `tagId`
        from `status`
        group by `tagId`) t on s.`statusId` = t.`statusId` and s.`tagId` = t.`tagId`
    ) f 
inner join (
    select s.*
    from `status` s
    inner join (
        select min(`statusId`) as `statusId`, `tagId`
        from `status`
        group by `tagId`) t on s.`statusId` = t.`statusId` and s.`tagId` = t.`tagId`
    ) l on f.`tagId` = l.`tagId`
order by tagId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d112/4/0)**:

```
| tagId |       date | statusType |
|-------|------------|------------|
|   101 | 2010-01-01 |   delivery |
|   102 | 2010-01-01 |     single |
|   103 | 2010-01-01 |     single |
|   104 | 2010-01-01 |     single |
|   105 | 2010-01-01 |     single |
```

Subquery `f` is the first record by each group and `l` is the last record by each group, and if you want `height` or `weight` column, please choose one of them which you prefer to.

Also you can `left join` this all query to `profile` then you can get `tagId` = 106, but this record will give you `null` for column `date` and `statusType`.